# Revisiting complexity of art gallery-like problem

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, polynomial-time

In a [question I had asked earlier](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/74641/time-complexity-of-art-gallery-like-problem), I was interested in knowing whether we could decide in polynomial time whether, for a directed graph $G$ with every one of its vertices belonging to an edge, a size-$w$ watch set, with $w$ at least half the number of vertices in $G$, exists (see the linked question). Several users showed that, in fact, such a polynomial time decider does not exist.

I'm interested in whether a polynomial time decider exists for a variant of this problem. Now, suppose that $G = (V,E)$ is an $n$-vertex directed graph with the property that every vertex in $G$ has an edge entering it. That is, for each vertex $v \in V$, there is an edge $(u,v)$ in $E$. With this in mind, consider the problem of deciding whether, for a given $w \geq 2n/3$, $G$ has a size-$w$ watch set. With the constraint that every vertex has an edge entering it, I'm not sure that we are able to reduce from arbitrary directed graphs, as [Discrete lizard](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/74658/71190) showed we could do in my earlier question. What I suspect is that any graph of this type must have a size-$w$ watch set, with $w \geq 2n/3$.

Comment: Actually, I think I can prove by induction the conjecture I give in the last sentence. I'll see if I can come up with a solution.

Comment: I suggest you try random testing: generate a million small random graphs with this property; for each, find the smallest watch set (e.g., through exhaustive search); and check whether your conjecture seems to hold in every such case.  I bet this will either help give you higher confidence in the conjecture (that it's worth  your time to try to prove) or find a counterexample.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks, I'll try something like this.

Comment: @D.W. Personally, I find that directly trying to construct a counter example is more constructive than randomly letting 'someone else' experiment. In the case of experiments, you only really can understand anything if you actually find a counter example, otherwise you can only say that randomly searching for a counter-example is hard, which is essentially saying you don't understand anything! But if you try to construct a counter example, you often either get one or see _why_ it is hard to construct a counter-example, which will often lead to a proof! ...

Comment: ... Of course, experiments can be very useful to find tricky cases that you haven't been able to think of, but I only see the value if you have actually tried (and 'unsatisfyingly' failed!) to find tricky cases.